# How to export a variable in JavaScript within a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I have the following function:

```
export function request(
  searchKey,
  apiEndpoint,
  path,
  params,
  { additionalHeaders } = {}
) {
  const method = "POST";
  return _request(method, searchKey, apiEndpoint, path, params, {
    additionalHeaders
  }).then(response => {
    return response
      .json()
      .then(json => {
        var my_json = update(params)
        const result = { response: response, json: json };
        return result;
      })
  });
}
```

I want to export the variable `my_json` to another .js file. I already tried with `export { my_json }`, but it only works if I do that on the top of the document, which doesn't work in my case. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You can create global variable and then export it at the end. But what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: What is the exact scenario that you are trying to solve?

Comment: did you try store your function into a variable?: export let request = () => {}

Comment: You want to build a service

Comment: I am using elasticsearch in order to build a search engine. Unfortunately elasticsearch doesn‘t provide the functionality that I need and it has some bugs when I modify it according to my needs. So basically, I want to override the output of the Connector API, which is in another file, with the json stored in my_json. I create it at that point, because there are the relevant parameters that I need in order to build my json file.

Comment: If you hadn't deleted your new question just now, I would have been able to complete the comment I was writing to help you on your way. That was a lot of wasted effort now. :(

Comment: I am sorry, but someone reported the question and it got deleted from his side :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't export a variable which is inside a function but you can definitely get the value stored in  `my_json` by the help of a `callback` function written in another javascript file.
Try using:

```
export function request(
  searchKey,
  apiEndpoint,
  path,
  params,
  { additionalHeaders } = {},
  callback
) {
  const method = "POST";
  return _request(method, searchKey, apiEndpoint, path, params, {
    additionalHeaders
  }).then(response => {
    return response
      .json()
      .then(json => {
        var my_json = update(params);
        callback(my_json);
        const result = { response: response, json: json };
        return result;
      })
  });
}
```

and in the other file define a function callback like:

```
function callback(data){
    // assign this data to another variable so that one can use it
    console.log(data)
}
```

and while calling the request function add one more argument as callback.

Hope this helps.